# Difference between icmp and icmpv6 for ip6tables?

Tags: iptables, ipv6, icmp, icmpv6

I found the following lines in a firewall script on one of our Linux servers (kernel 5.x)

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

The two commands both run without error, but I'm confused about it. I can only figure out that `ipv6-icmp` is a synonym for `icmpv6`, but what is `icmp` in the context of IPv6 iptables (or `ip6tables(8)`)?

Comment: It is kind of funny that this 3 year old question has no response. I find it really confusing also. Thanks for having posted it anyway. I still did not find the answer !

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](https://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/02/09/ip6tables-ipv6-icmp-vs-icmp/) says icmp rule will not work.
I tested that and I can confirm, "`icmp`" rules in context of ip6tables is a non-working rule.
wile `icmpv6` works just fine